# GTK+2.0 and GTK+3.0 Installation issue in Raspberry pi Wheezy

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

- I want to run GTK application into my Raspberry Pi Model B(V1.2) board.I'm using Raspbian Debian Whezzy for development.
- For that i need to install GTK2/3 packages to install.When I'm giving command **sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev** ,it gives following error,

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

- I've tried to solve that error using command **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get install -f** to fix issues.but not able to solve that issue.

Need help.Thanks

Comment: Did you try running `sudo apt-get update` before `install` ? Also, let us know output of `uname -a`.

Comment: yes..i've written in my question..just check once.. **uname -a :Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux**

Comment: My bad. and `uname -a` ?

Comment: uname -a : **Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux**

Comment: I'm able to install it without any problems. But I have an RPi 2 and I'm running latest kernel ie `4.0.6`

Comment: Means is there any problem with kernel version?and are you using debian Raspberian wheezy..Downloaded from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ ?

Comment: Do you actually need gtk2 and 3?  I've installed gtk3 without problems for several years on several different Pis.

Comment: @Ronil Not really. Kernel should be fine. Not sure why it is happening. Let me test it on another pi running the same kernel.

Comment: @Ronil Nope. Works fine on other Pi as well.

Comment: can u please give me **source.list** file?

Answer (score 5):

- Problem solved. Actually I've made some local change in **sources.list** file according to local server.Now I've changed it and make it as original.
- Use **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev**(for gtk-3) or **sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev**(for gtk-2) Now its working.